# Cannot import library Graph from python

Tags: graph, neo4j, py2neo

I installed py2neo on Centos Red-hat .Now i'm trying to connect py2neo with Neo4j. I typed "python" in the Shell to open a python environment.Then "from py2neo import Graph". I get the following error :"cannot import name Graph". 
I don't know what's the problem exactly.

Working with python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

Show your response from command in python environment:

```
import py2neo; dir(py2neo)
```

Comment: i get  "autor" "builtins" 'copyright" "doc" "licence" "name" "package" "path" "version" "cypher" "neo4j" "node" "rl" "rest" "util"

Comment: also show output from: `py2neo.version` and `py2neo.__dict__`

Comment: I guess that you use old version like this one: http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/

Comment: I typed "py2neo.version"  but command not found. Do you mean that i shoudd update py2neo?

Comment: maybe this: `py2neo.__version__`

Comment: Did you run this command in python environment? If not, you should do this.

Comment: it 's version 1.5 :)

Comment: when i do "yum update py2neo"  it says no package py2neo available. i'm just stuck and can't work nothing for my project if this thing is not solved, help !

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention how you installed py2neo but it sounds like the python executable you are running simply cannot see the py2neo package. You have probably installed incorrectly for that version of python.

Please note though that no recent releases of py2neo support python 2.6. For that reason, I recommend you upgrade.